# How is this a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closing

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54023/how-can-i-bed-each-of-the-available-characters-as-either-gender

The question asks for much more detail, and different information than the linked 'duplicate'.  Why was this closed?  I can change the title if it's offending someone, but honestly...

Comment: I think there's some relevant discussion about this sort of broad "guides" question [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/list-questions-for-the-old-republic-mmos-cw-closure-other).  I think if you have a specific problem figuring out what to do with a particular character and can't find info elsewhere, then asking about that specifically is fine.  But SE isn't a good place to host wiki-style guides/walkthroughs covering so much ground.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw two problems with your original question.

First, the "Who can I bang?" part was already covered by [Who can I romance?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53601/3062).

Secondly, the "how" is a broad question when applied to that many characters, and will attract a very generic answer (i.e., "Talk to them and say nice things").

For those reasons, I think the question as it stands should be closed. I see two options:

- Expand the scope of the duplicate question to cover the generic answer of "how". This is a pretty trivial change to that question.
- The better option I think, is to post a question about how to romance a specific character that you're interested in. This will give you a more meaningful answer about specific dialog options and other triggers you will need to choose.

And yes, editing the title would be good, but if that was the only issue, the title could be edited. Even with an unoffensive title, the question as it stands has problems.

Comment: if they're all similar in practice, that's still a valid answer, but I'm assuming at least a few of them are going to have unique approaches, given the multiple gender thing?

Comment: @GnomeSlice I can't say for sure, but I really doubt it, based on Bioware's record in Dragon Age and past ME games. It's pretty much always "talk to them until they like you enough". Plus, I'm pretty sure FemShep could romance Liara in previous games, so despite the big controversy, this isn't the first ME game with same-sex relationships.

Comment: That said, if you're specifically curious about how to trigger the same-sex relationship, asking how to romance Cortez would probably be a good question.

Answer (score 18):

Truth be told, I'm getting sick of looking at your questions that are intentionally (borderline?) inappropriate just to get people to attract clicks and/or controversy.  I look for any reason to close your questions just so they'll go away, or in the hopes that you'll eventually realize it is far more childish than humorous and doesn't contribute anything to the site.

Comment: @GnomeSlice If it requires an "assumption" about what's appropriate enough for the site, then you should consider rephrasing.  I shared my thoughts on a closely related topic [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4031/4775)

Comment: Alright, I'll rephrase that:  'Bang' is a little juvenile, but I couldn't think of any more concise way to put it, and it's not really a vulgar term.

Comment: While I agree that this particular habit of gnomes is... Tiresome, I maintain that in *most* cases, the proper solution is to Downvote, not close. That said, I think half of this question is a dupe and the other half is far too broad to be useful, so even cleaned up its a good candidate for closure.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. But I also see where others are coming from.

Edit your question to be less about who you can "bang", and more about "how" (which the other question doesn't address) you can go about "banging", and I'll reopen it. (Perhaps focusing on how to achieve the Paramour achievement?)

And while you're at it, editing the tone wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Is that any better?

Comment: @Raven The existing question *does* ask for specification on which romances count for the Paramour achievement.

Comment: @Raven I'm not asking about the Paramour achievement.